# How to edit existing .xls Excel file using PHP

Tags: php, phpexcel, xls

I am trying to edit my existing .xls Excel file. But i can't find the proper way to edit existing .xls excel file.

I had used PHPEXCEL for reading the .xls file and then writing the .xls file. But in that I lost some excel functionality like 'macro', 'vb form' from existing .xls file.

In my case, I need to update my Excel file day by day. So currently I am using PHPEXCEL, first I need to read Excel then write it with a new record.

So I am finding the way to edit existing .xls file with my new record.

Please share your idea if you find.

Comment: post whatever code already you tried...

Answer (score 0):

If you need support for macros and forms, then you're pretty limited in your choices. There's only 3 options available:

- Ilia Alshanetsky's [Excel extension](http://ilia.ws/archives/222-PHP-Excel-Extension.html) now on [github](https://github.com/iliaal/php_excel) (requires commercial [libXL](http://www.libxl.com/) component)
- PHP's [COM extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) (requires a COM enabled spreadsheet program such as MS Excel or OpenOffice Calc running on the server)
- The Open Office alternative to COM ([PUNO](http://www.wstech2.net/index.php?do=0a,01,05)) (requires Open/Libre Office installed on the server with Java support enabled)